# How can I change the text size in Excel using VBA without selecting the shape?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to change the text size in a textbox in Excel using VBA. I currently have the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("textEnemy")).Visible = True
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("textEnemy")).Select
With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
    .Text = msg
    For i = 1 To 15
        .Font.Size = i * 10
        Call WasteTime(50)
    Next
End With
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("textEnemy")).Visible = False
```

This code animates the text increasing in size, and then it disappears. The problem is that when I run this code the textbox is selected (there is a box around it). How can I achieve the same goal without selecting the textbox/showing the selection border around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Delete this line: `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("textEnemy")).Select`? Work with the object directly.

Comment: My issue is that it doesn't seem to work if I try to work with it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to set the textbox as a shape variable, and then adjust it.

```
Sub Animate(playerCode As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim msg As String
    Dim textBox As Shape
    msg = "HIT!"

    Set textBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("textUser")

    'Animate textbox
    textBox.Visible = True
    With textBox.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
        .Text = msg
        For i = 1 To 15
            .Font.Size = i * 10
            Call WasteTime(50)
        Next
    End With
    textBox.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

As @findwindow says:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("textEnemy"))

    .Visible = True

    With .ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
        .Text = msg
        For i = 1 To 15
            .Font.Size = i * 10
            Call WasteTime(50)
        Next
    End With

    .Visible = False

End With
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this before posting and it doesn't work. I am getting an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error with "With .ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters" highlighted.